# How to split row of data into columns separated by comma in python

Tags: python, numpy

I have a text file in the following format that I am trying to convert into rows and columns:

```
red,red,blue
blue,red,blue 
blue,blue,red
```

Once the conversion is complete, I want to store the above in a `rows` variable:

```
row[0] # should return 'red red blue'
row[0][2] # should return 'blue'
```

So far I have gotten as far as:

```
file = open('myfile.txt')
for row in file:
    # do something here
```

But i'm not sure what to do next.. can someone help? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use the [csv module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html). You've tagged this with numpy; are you trying to do this with pure python or numpy?

Comment: Take a look at numpy `genfromtxt()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solution without any external modules :

```
output = []

with open('file.txt', 'r') as reading:
    file_input = reading.read().split('\n')

for row in file_input:
    output.append(row.split(','))

print(output)
```

Comment: Why wouldn't you use the csv module? It's part of core python and anyway, the question is tagged with numpy.

Comment: Just a nit, in case someone is going to copy-paste this: `output` can be initialized just before the loop, and even better, using a list comprehension.

Comment: yes you can optimize the code, just a simple quick solution. You can suggest edits if you want.

Comment: Yes you can, i was referring to numpy and pandas @roganjosh

Comment: I don't get what you're saying. Ok, pandas and numpy are separate, but if you're doing this in pure python you could still use the csv module.

Comment: Yes absolutely, but by external modules I meant numpy and pandas. @roganjosh

Comment: So... Why did you give a solution where you had to manually split by commas?

Comment: For simplicity's sake. I totally agree it can be done with csv, OK? @roganjosh

Comment: The issue being that without the csv module, you end up with more lines of code and have to iterate the file contents twice. That's not simplicity.

Comment: Simplicity in understanding, I know its lengthy. Anyways feel free to add your csv method as an edit to my answer.

Answer (score 6):

**1.numpy solution**: (because numpy tag)

Use [`numpy.genfromtxt`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html) for numpy array:

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.genfromtxt('file.txt',dtype='str',delimiter=',')
print (arr)
[['red' 'red' 'blue']
 ['blue' 'red' 'blue']
 ['blue' 'blue' 'red']]

print (arr[0])
['red' 'red' 'blue']

print (arr[0][2])
blue
```

**2.pandas solution**:

Use [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) for `DataFrame` and for select values [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('file.txt', header=None)
print (df)
      0     1      2
0   red   red   blue
1  blue   red   blue
2  blue  blue    red

#select first row to Series
print (df.loc[0])
0     red
1     red
2    blue
Name: 0, dtype: object

#select value by index and column
print (df.loc[0, 2])
blue
```

**3.pure python solutions**:

If want nested lists use `nested list comprehension`:

```
data = [[item for item in line.rstrip('\r\n').split(',')] 
         for line in open('file.txt')]
print (data)

[['red', 'red', 'blue'], ['blue', 'red', 'blue'], ['blue', 'blue', 'red']]
```

Or with module `csv`:

```
import csv

reader = csv.reader(open("file.txt"), delimiter=',')
data = [word for word in [row for row in reader]]
print (data)

[['red', 'red', 'blue'], ['blue', 'red', 'blue'], ['blue', 'blue', 'red']]
```

---

```
print (data[0])
['red', 'red', 'blue']

print (data[0][2])
blue
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternative solution with **pandas** module which is good for `csv` files processing:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('file.txt', header=None).T

print(df[0].tolist())    # ['red', 'red', 'blue']
print(df[0][2])          # blue
```